# running rails g devise:install generates seg fault in os x 10.8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite, rvm

Im using the latest rvm, latest ruby and when running various things dealing with the database i get random seg faults with both mysql2 and sqlite3.

```
#Ruby Version
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.0.0]

#Ruby Location
$ which ruby
/Users/mikedevita/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

#RVM Version
-> rvm -v
rvm 1.15.8 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

**I have tried deleting my gemset, and reinstalling them and i still get similar errors to this (this is my last):**

```
➜ rails g devise:install
/Users/mikedevita/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@callcenter/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

i just noticed, its running from the right rvm location, but it says ruby 1.8.7 below it?

i am using zsh & oh-my-zsh.. so here is part of my .zshrc pertaining to my PATH settings:

```
# Customize to your needs...
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
# Load RVM function
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin

#MySQL
PATH=$PATH:"/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/bin"
```

## update 1

now im getting a larger seg fault message w/ sqlite3
https://gist.github.com/5717423dbc37286761e1

Comment: have you tried `rvm implode`, `gem update --system` and running other rails projects?

Comment: i have, i just wiped my system as we speak.. so hopefully starting scratch might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two possibilities:

1. you did not use a ruby:

   ```
   rvm use 1.9.3@callcenter
   ```
2. you build ruby using clang - this is known to generate the `[BUG] Segmentation fault` errors.

Recompile your ruby using gcc-4.2 from gnu (read `rvm requirements` for instructions):

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
rvm 1.9.3@gloabal,1.9.3,1.9.3@callcenter do rvm gemset pristine
```

Comment: i am using jewelrybox, so after installing gcc-4.2 i should not click the use clang button right?

Comment: got all working now after a fresh install of os x, just cant get pow to work.. switching back to shotgun/webrick

Comment: and now shotgun/webrick takes forrrever to load the page blah

Comment: running `rails s` i have no problems but when i run `shotgun -d` i get tons of errors in console.

Comment: "Use clang" is in JewelryBox for those who wish to experiment with it and should not be used unless you know what you're doing. Be sure to install gcc-4.2 as suggested above from either homebrew or osx-gcc-installer.